# ShoDaSa bAhu NrsiMhASTkam

Tags: stotra, narasimha, hymn

I am looking for Sanskrit text for Shodasha baahu [narasimhashtakam](https://youtu.be/nABS0bs3Noc).
Which is composed by Vijayendra Teertha of Madhwa line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shodasha baahu Nrusimha stotram is available on Sanskrit Documents Website.

Link : [Shri ShoDashabAhunRisiMhAShTakam .](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_vishhnu/nrisimhAShTakam2.html)

We can read this in different languages and transliteration scripts on the website.

Comment: Why the spelling is "Nrusimha"?

Comment: @Krishna The name of the Lord is written as Nṛsiṁha according to the transliteration scheme, see at https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/5/18/14 and some people write it as Nrisimha, and others write it as Nrusimha. Similarly Krishna and Krushna for Kṛṣṇa. See about Devanagari transliteration for Sanskrit at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devanagari_transliteration

Comment: @Krishna As Brahma Jijnasa stated, Nrusimha is a near transliteration of the name Nṛsiṁha without using dialectics. The difference is due to 'ru' in the name Nrusimha. Nrusimha and Narasimha both are the names of same avatr of Lord Vishnu but the results we get when we chant the name are different. Narasimha, Naarasimha, Nrusimha. Three are the names but the results are different.